# Redefining the quote environment

Tags: environments, quoting

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this:

```
%%Tweaked quote environment
\let\origquote\quote
\renewenvironment{\quote}{%
  \vspace{-0.5\parskip}
  \origquote
}%
{\endorigquote}
```

My goal is to reduce the spacing above a quote environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Environments are written without backslash, in `\renewenvironment`
- Define also `\endorigquote`

```
\let\origquote\quote
\let\endorigquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
  \vspace{-0.5\parskip}
  \origquote
}%
{\endorigquote}
```