# Change the font of the block quote?

Tags: fonts, environments, fontspec, quoting

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find the right way of doing this.

I want to redefine my `quote` and `quotation` commands to use a different font. My main font is `Linux Libertine O` (I am using fontspec), and I want to use the *small* version of `Linux Biolinum O` inside my quotations.

Among some of the commands I've tried is this, but it ain't working:

```
\let\quoteOld\quote
\renewenvironment{quote}{\fontspec{Linux Biolinum O}\small\quoteOld}
```

Bonus question: What do I need to learn, in order to figure out how to achieve the above by myself? I would appreciate a book or resource to read.

Comment: On some learning resources: [What's the best book to start learning LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693).  Also, there's a *lot* of good information here.  For example, searching for `renewenvironment` led to [Redefining the quote environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35918/2693) which asks a very similar question (with a similar problem).

Comment: I guess I am asking what I need to learn/read so that I could figure out anything by myself - not only the `renewenvironment` command... That link looks good! Thanks

Comment: I understand your question, I was just saying that searching here for almost anything will turn up some good results. The `renewcommand` was just an (apropos) example.

Comment: I guess I also don't want to learn about all the font features that do not related to Xetex - as it does things completely differently from what I understand. Most of the books out there -  cover the font with the use of the babel and such.

Comment: Well books are always a bit behind (unless they've just been published.)  The `fontspec` documentation is probably all you need to know about font handling in XeLaTeX; you can ignore almost all of the rest. See also [How do I use a particular font for a small section of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As I've commented on one of your other questions, you shouldn't use `\fontspec` to change fonts, but define a new fontfamily.  The `etoolbox` package provides simple patching commands.  For this you can just use its `\AtBeginEnvironment` command.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\quotefont{Linux Biolinum O}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\quotefont\small}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{quote}
A quotation.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code snippet is missing the third required argument of `\renewenvironment` which specifies the code to be executed at the end of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\quotefont}{Linux Biolinum O}

\let\quoteOld\quote
\let\endquoteOld\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{\quotefont\small\quoteOld}{\endquoteOld}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - do you get hired immediately anywhere if you have 90k rep on tex.se?

Answer (score 3):

After adding the `fontspec` code for your font, just change the quote size.

```
% Using 'xelatex'
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\small}

\begin{document}
 Normal text.

\begin{quote}
    This is a quote.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

The line: `\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\small}` works without adding any other package.