# How to create "local" footnotes in block quotes?

Tags: footnotes, quoting

I have a block quote, which contains a footnote - but I don't want to put that at the end of the page, but rather at the end of the quote. Like so:

[image]

Does `footnote` command allow this kind of customization? If not - where should I look? Much appreciated!

Comment: I think the package `parnotes` is worth reading the documentation. It resulted BTW from this TeX.SX question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34746/placing-footnotes-or-endnotes-at-the-end-of-the-current-paragraph.

Comment: I was *so* getting ready to pimp my package, but minipages are a better solution if (1) the content is all on one page, and (2) you want to use the default footnote formatting. Personally, though, I'd set the footnotes off with rules on *both* sides, as in one of the examples I gave – and for that `parnotes` is much easier than hacking the footnote code.

Comment: @Speravir does it allow for custom footnote number? In my example both footnotes should be numbered 4, because they are essentially the footnotes from the original work.

Comment: @drozzy: I honestly do not know, how to do that. Looking into the source of that package there are **two** counters, and I don’t know which one must be advanced and how. You should BTW have been clearer, that you needed on the customized counter. (Seeing your questions resp. the examples there: You do write a text about Fibonacci, don’t you?)

Comment: @rdhs: Do you see a way for customizing the parnote counter, such as adding a `\theparnote` or similar? See my comment to @drozzy, too.

Comment: @Speravir Yeah, that's just a command I forgot about: `\makeatletter\def\parnotesetto#1{\c@PN@t=#1\c@PN@n=#1}\makeatother` should work. I'll work on also adding a `\parnote[...]{...}` command with `nccfoots`-like behavior.

Comment: @Speravir Just a caveat: Don't use it when there are still parnotes left to be set. So the usage in this case would be `\begin{quote}\parnotesetto{4}French text...\parnotes\parnotessetto{4}Tenslation...\parnotes\end{quote}`.

Comment: @Speravir Sorry for not being clear. I only realized it should be customized after I posted it and started seeing responses. (Yes, a book)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anticipating your follow-up questions based on this question: [Change the font of the block quote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47306/2693) here's a solution with minipages that also gets the formatting of the footnote and the marker correct.  I've also created a `\qfootnote` command (adapting Gonzalo's idea) which takes 3 arguments: the first optional argument specifies the formatting for the footnote marker.  The second argument is the footnote number. Since the quoted footnotes will be arbitrarily numbered, it makes sense to set them manually inside each quote. The third argument is the footnote text. This command includes Gonzalo's modifications to the footnote marker indentation.  This gives you maximum flexibility on the formatting of the footnotes in the quote.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\quotefont{Linux Biolinum O}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\quotefont\small}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@mpfootnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize\quotefont}{}{}
\newcommand\qfootnote[3][arabic]{%
       \defcounter{mpfootnote}{#2-1}%
       \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[.5em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}%
       \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\quotefont\csname#1\endcsname{mpfootnote}}%
       \footnote{#3}}
% Use of the \qfootnote command:
% \qfootnote[<format>]{<number>}{<text>} (default is arabic)
% example: \qfootnote[alph]{3}{text} will yield 'c' as the footnote marker.
% example: \qfootnote[roman]{4}{text} will yield 'iv' as the marker
% example: \qfootnote{2}{text} will yield '2' as the marker
\begin{document}
Some text. This is the main text.\footnote{This is a footnote in the main text.}
\begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
This is a quotation with a footnote in it.\qfootnote[alph]{4}{A footnote in the
minipage} The footnote is numbered independently of the rest of the text.
\end{minipage}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

**Simplified version**

The first version of this answer had a simpler solution.  If you know that your footnotes will always have the same kind of numbering system, then you can just use regular footnote commands inside a minipage and have a simple command `\quotefnum` to set the footnote number. I've left in the quote font modifications from your previous question. If you don't need a different font for the quote environment, then this can be made even simpler by removing the `AtBeginEnvironment` line and the `\patchcmd` line, and removing `\quotefont` from the redefinition of `\thempfootnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\quotefont{Linux Biolinum O}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\quotefont\small}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@mpfootnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize\quotefont}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\quotefnum[1]{\defcounter{mpfootnote}{#1-1}}

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\quotefont\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}
Some text. This is the main text.\footnote{This is a footnote in the main text.}
\begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\quotefnum{4}
This is a quotation with a footnote in it.\footnote{A footnote in the minipage}. The footnote is numbered independently of the rest of the text.
\end{minipage}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great - the custom numbering is exactly what I  needed. But which parts are actually required to make this work - for example, do I need `makeatletter` and `patchcmd` lines?

Comment: On `\makeatletter` see [What to \makeatletter and \makeatother do](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/2693). The `\patchcmd` changes the minipage footnotes to `\quotefont` to match your quote environment.  The first `\renewcommand` sets the indentation for the footnotes. The second makes the footnote marker numeric.  So all are needed, yes.

Comment: So... if I don't want to change the fonts, I can omit the patchcmd?

Comment: Yes, and remove `\quotefont` from the second `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Why do we need the `\noindent\makebox` commands? I mean, why doesn't it just put the footnote counter into text without spaces around it?

Comment: @drozzy Minipage footnotes default to `\alph` formatting (a,b,c ...) which is why you get 'd'.  I've modified my solution to make it more general: now you can specify both the footnote marker and its format in a single command (similar in spirit to Gonzalo's solution.)

Comment: @drozzy Gonzalo and I are mainly trying to overcome the default formatting of footnotes, which is indented.  So that's why the `\noindent ...` is needed.

Answer (score 13):

A possible simple approach would be to use a `minipage` inside the `quote` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
\lipsum[1] text\footnote{this is a footnote} text text text.
\end{minipage}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an enhanced version of my answer: now everything is dome through a new environment `fnquote` that redefines and steps appropriately the counter and formats the footnote mark as in the image (suppressing the indentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fnquote}
  {\begin{quote}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\stepcounter{footnote}
  \renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[1.2em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{quote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{fnquote}
\lipsum[1] text\footnote{this is a footnote} text text text.
\end{fnquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new version; a new command \qtfootnote is available allowing to manually specify the value for the footnote marker:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{tmpfn}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fnquote}
  {\begin{quote}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[1.2em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}
  }
  {\end{minipage}\end{quote}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\qtfootnote[2]{%
  \setcounter{tmpfn}{\thempfootnote}%
  \setcounter{mpfootnote}{#1}\addtocounter{mpfootnote}{-1}%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \setcounter{mpfootnote}{\thetmpfn}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{fnquote}
\lipsum[1] text\qtfootnote{5}{this is a footnote} text text text.
\end{fnquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the fourth version, now the code has been greatly simplified by using the features provided by the `nccfoots` package; now the footnote marker can be freely assigned (arabic, alphabetic, roman, etc.) in an easy way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccfoots}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fnquote}
  {\begin{quote}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[1em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{quote}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\qtfootnote[2]{\Footnotemark{#1}\Footnotetext{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\Text
\begin{fnquote}
\Text text text text text\qtfootnote{4}{this is a footnote} text text.
\end{fnquote}
\begin{fnquote}
\Text text text text text\qtfootnote{d}{this is a footnote} text text.
\end{fnquote}
\begin{fnquote}
\Text text text text text\qtfootnote{IV}{this is a footnote} text text.
\end{fnquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks cool. What is the `minipage`(is there a doc for it somewhere)? And what does the `linewidth` argument do inside of it?

Comment: A `minipage` is basically what it says: a small page within a page. The `\linewidth` argument sets the width of it to the width of the line.  You might want to browse through the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) for lots of accurate online info.

Comment: @drozzy: I've updated my answer; now you can manually specify the footnote marker.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why are you using `footnote` as the counter and not `mpfootnote`?

Comment: @AlanMunn: good question! I initially (for some reason I can't remember) redefined `\thempfootnote` to depend on `footnote` and I kept using `footnote`. However, it seems cleaner to use `mpfootnote`, so I'll do the changes.

Comment: @drozzy: I've updated my answer with a fourth, much simpler solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can place the "insides" of the `quote` in a `minipage` of width `\linewidth`. Footnotes within a `minipage` will be purged at closure.

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum laoreet tincidunt convallis. Praesent eu purus 
mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus convallis neque 
rutrum lorem imperdiet egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi 
posuere convallis mauris quis imperdiet.
\begin{quote}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    Nunc suscipit gravida sollicitudin. Donec molestie libero nunc, 
    ac adipiscing odio. Pellentesque consectetur\footnote{Pellentesque 
    sed ante id nisl iaculis sagittis.} nulla vel nunc 
    blandit dapibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
  \end{minipage}
\end{quote}
Morbi sodales arcu enim, et accumsan ante. Mauris sed ante erat. 
Praesent scelerisque metus ac mauris placerat vehicula. 
Nam tristique faucibus felis sed consectetur.
\end{document}
```

Footnote numbering can be modified, as needed. Perhaps more advisable is to define a `blockquote` environment that is all-inclusive:

```
\newenvironment{blockquote}[1]
  {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}% \begin{blockquote}
   \item\relax\minipage{\linewidth}%
   \setcounter{mpfootnote}{\numexpr#1-1}%
   \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}}
  {\endminipage\endlist}% \end{blockquote}
```

Now you can use

```
%...
\begin{blockquote}{5}
  Nunc suscipit gravida sollicitudin. Donec molestie libero nunc, 
  ac adipiscing odio. Pellentesque consectetur\footnote{Pellentesque 
  sed ante id nisl iaculis sagittis.} nulla vel nunc 
  blandit dapibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
  parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
\end{blockquote}
%...
```

which yields a number-specific footnote:

[image]

Specifying such specific references might not mesh well with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Additional definitions can now be included in the `blockquote` environment.

Comment: I like your example because it's simple... but I also want to specify the footnote number to be 4.

Comment: @drozzy: I've updated my answer to now take an optional number-specific argument.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for everyone for their answers! Here is what I did in the end - which was a simplification and unification of some of the ideas expressed in the answers.

My class defines a custom command:

```
% Set the footnote number inside a minipage to a custom number
\newcommand*\footnoteNum[1]{%
    \defcounter{mpfootnote}{#1-1}
    % Set numbering to arabic
    \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}}
```

and then I use it in text as follows:

```
\begin{quote}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\footnoteNum{4} 
        “C douzième siècle,\footnote{``Publicus scriba.''}
        que le célèbre mathématicien Léonard Bonacci de            
        l’arithmétique, de l’algèbre et de la géométrie.
    \end{minipage}
\end{quote}
```

The reason I like this approach is:

1. It leaves the usual environments like `quote` unmodified. No need to remember a weird sounding name.
2. It calls the `footnote` command by it's original name - again, no need to remember a custom command name.
3. It follows the common sense of a regular footnote: if the user does not wrap it up in a minipage, footnote will appear at the bottom of the page.
4. `footnoteNum` command, while not obvious, will be an easy to figure out, since, after compiling the document and finding that the footnote number is `a`, the user will suspect that he missed something, and remember to set the footnote number.

Again, thanks to everyone for answering - but there was no one answer that exactly what I needed, so for future generations I wanted to provide my own version. :-)

Comment: You don't need `\makeatletter`, `\makeatothe` (you missed an `r`), since you do not use the `@` sign for a letter.

Comment: So essentially this is the first version of my answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hm... you are right! Could you add that to the answer? I knew it took it from somewhere, but in my drunken state forget from where.