# Using nccfoots package with Tufte package

Tags: footnotes, tufte

I have been using tufte-book for a while but am trying to get the nccfoots package to work within the quotes (eg. the footnote within the shaded quotation area). Thanks.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,justified,marginals=raggedouter,notoc,openany]{tufte-book}
    %---------------------------------------%
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    %---------------------------------------%
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %---------------------------------------%
    % UCL style guide black - can call on these colours
    \definecolor{ucl1black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{ucl2black}{RGB}{75,75,75}
    \definecolor{ucl3black}{RGB}{128,128,128}
    \definecolor{ucl4black}{RGB}{205,205,205}
    % UCL style guide stone
    \definecolor{ucl3stone}{RGB}{236,234,229}
    %---------------------------------------%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    % chapter format
    \titleformat{\chapter}%
      {\huge\rmfamily\itshape\color{ucl1black}}% format applied to label+text
      {\llap{\colorbox{ucl1black}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\huge\color{white}\thechapter}}}}% label
      {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {}% before the title body
      []% after the title body

    % section format
    \titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\Large\itshape\color{black}}% format applied to label+text
      {\llap{\colorbox{ucl2black}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\textbf{\thesection}}}}}% label
      {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {}% before the title body
      []% after the title body

    % subsection format
    \titleformat{\subsection}%
      {\normalfont\large\itshape\color{black}}% format applied to label+text
      {\llap{\colorbox{ucl3black}{\parbox{1.5cm}{\hfill\color{white}\textbf{\thesubsection}}}}}% label
      {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
      {}% before the title body
      []% after the title body
    %---------------------------------------%
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize\itshape}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \color{ucl1black}
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{245,245,245}
    \renewenvironment{quote}[1][\hsize]
    {%
        \def\FrameCommand
        {%
    {\color{ucl3stone}\vrule width 2pt}%
            \hspace{10pt}%must no space.
            \fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{gray!5}
        }%
        \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
    }
    {\endMakeFramed}
    %---------------------------------------%
    \newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
    \newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
    \newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
    \newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment
    \newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
    \newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
    \newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
    \newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name
    %---------------------------------------%
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    %---------------------------------------%
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1]
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{quote}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{quote}
    \footnote{\lipsum[1]}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! - was just wondering how to get footnotes within quotes similar to the nccfoots package used in this article:  <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47467/how-to-create-local-footnotes-in-block-quotes>

Comment: it seems to conflict with my shading code that i have for my quotation blocks already..

Comment: Can you maybe add your comments to your question and maybe extend them a little bit so the problem description becomes a bit more clear?