# Place footnotes under quoted text with \quoting

Tags: footnotes, quoting

I'm using the `quoting` package environment to ... quote some text! And I'm trying to have some footnotes, related to the content of the quote, appear right under it.

I've tried to use the minipage method, [as demonstrated here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47467/how-to-create-local-footnotes-in-block-quotes), but have failed to implement it: the text of the quote doesn't stay in its column, for instance, or I get an error message.

I've pasted the code that I have now and that works.

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% QUOTE TEXT MARGINS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}

% FOOTNOTES IN QUOTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=\parindent]
    Immob was this too! A landscape of bleak solemnities punctuated with pratfalls both programmed and unprogrammed\footnote{Computers!}! A nation of unsmiling priests top-heavy with mission and frozen-mugged with dedication, stopping every so often, at every pratfall, to laugh at unholy glee at themselves\footnote{Your dog is nice.} and each other–at the symbols of their mission and the objects of their dedication. Here was ambivalence with a vengeance: a whole\footnote{The cake is pink.} inspired people plunging the dagger of the horselaugh into the bowels of its inspiration.
\end{quoting}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}...\end{minipage} may help you to meet your requirement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)'s good [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47470/31034) is sufficent for you.

```
    \documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
    \special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    % QUOTE TEXT MARGINS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}

    % FOOTNOTES IN QUOTATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{nccfoots}
    \makeatletter
    \newenvironment{fnquote}
      {\begin{quote}\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[1em][l]{\@makefnmark}##1}}
      {\end{minipage}\end{quote}}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand\qtfootnote[2]{\Footnotemark{#1}\Footnotetext{#1}{#2}}

    \begin{document}

    \blindtext

    \begin{fnquote}
Immob was this too! A landscape of bleak solemnities punctuated with pratfalls both programmed and unprogrammed\qtfootnote{*}{Computers!}! A nation of unsmiling priests top-
heavy with mission and frozen-mugged with dedication, stopping every so often, at every
 pratfall, to laugh at unholy glee at themselves\qtfootnote{\#}{Your dog is nice.} and
 each other–at the symbols of their mission and the objects of their dedication. Here was
 ambivalence with a vengeance: a whole\qtfootnote{\$}{The cake is pink.} inspired people
 plunging the dagger of the horselaugh into the bowels of its inspiration.
    \end{fnquote}

    \blindtext

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 it is right for the question of circuitikz :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, Thank you :-). But, really it is not necessary. Thank you again.

Comment: For me it is important...I like the correctness and give to Caesar what is Caesar's